# SELECT FROM table with conditional SELECT check

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-in

I have a table `foo` with following two columns. The `reference_uid` can be same for `type` CREATE and DELETE.

```
+======================================================+
|  reference_uid                         |    type     | 
+======================================================+
| 180f28e3-6abd-45a8-b84c-410e908e62ed   | CREATE      | 
| 180f28e3-6abd-45a8-b84c-410e908e62ed   | DELETE      | 
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

below query returns me both row;

```
SELECT type FROM foo WHERE `reference_uid` = '180f28e3-6abd-45a8-b84c-410e908e62ed';
```

But I want such query that returns me only one row. If row with type = DELETE exists, then return me  row with type DELETE, else return the row with type CREATE (Note row with type=CREATE will always exist).

I guess I need to create SELECT within SELECT statement ? 
my fail tries are;

```
 SELECT type FROM foo WHERE type IN (SELECT type FROM foo WHERE `reference_uid` = '180f28e3-6abd-45a8-b84c-410e908e62ed') WHERE type = "DELETE";
```

Comment: It seems like you mean "rows", when you say "column"?

Comment: thanks ... corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also go with a simple combination of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `foo`
WHERE `reference_uid` = '180f28e3-6abd-45a8-b84c-410e908e62ed'
ORDER BY `type` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just try this:

```
SELECT
    reference_uid,
    MAX(type) AS max_type
FROM foo
WHERE reference_uid = '180f28e3-6abd-45a8-b84c-410e908e62ed'
GROUP BY
    reference_uid;
```

This works because the text `DELETE` is lexicographically greater than `CREATE`, so the former would be selected first over the latter, assuming `DELETE` is present.  If `DELETE` *isn't* present, then by default it would just choose `CREATE`.